# LogicalCallContext doesn't flow between HttpApplication BeginRequest event and the rest of the request?

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I am trying to add some request context information to each request in a .NET Mvc application. I'm using the LogicalCallContext for this purpose since my requests sometimes invoke asynchronous tasks. However, I'm finding that items put in the logical call context during the BeginRequest event aren't available in action methods later in the pipeline. Can anyone explain this behavior? I'm using .NET 4.5.

Here's some sample code:

```
public class MyApp : HttpApplication
{
    public override void Init()
    {
        this.BeginRequest += (sender, args) => 
        {
            CallContext.LogicalSetData("MyRequestId", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        };
    }
}

// in the action method
public ActionResult Action() {
    var requestId = CallContext.LogicalGetData("MyRequestId");
    // requestId is null?!
}
```

Comment: Why you don't use HttpContext.Items for storing per request data?

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov: because HttpContext.Current doesn't flow along the logical flow of execution, so it doesn't handle multiple threads well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem, I'm using .NET 4.5, MVC 4. The data shows up, both from "MyApp" (Global.asax) and from a HttpModule (that I created while trying to trigger this issue).
Is it a clean project, containing only the code you provided, or can it be some other thing interfering with the CallContext? 
Is the problem always showing up or is it only under heavy load? (I even fiddled a bit with Gatling, but didn't have any issues then either)

Comment: I think you're right. I refactored my code a bit and this issue went away. My guess is that there was a bug in my call context manipulation code which has since disappeared. Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 3):

Events are handled one after another, and if any of the events ends asynchronously, the next event will be placed on the queue of the thread pool and be handled when there is a thread free.

The ASP.NET code uses the call context to keep track of the `HttpContext` within a thread, but that is specifically set when each event is handled, which means that you have a new call context for each event.

Here is an article that shows how the thread switching works between events:
http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?572-CallContext-vs-ThreadStatic-vs-HttpContext

To keep any data from one event to another, use the `HttpContext`.

If you are specifically starting new threads, they won't have the context, so then you have to provide them with references to any data that they need.

Comment: That's why I'm using the LogicalCallContext (which persists across ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem() calls, new Threads, async methods, etc. Any idea why it doesn't persist here?

Comment: @ChaseMedallion: The logical call context is originally intended for remote calls. From what I can see the data has to implement the `ILogicalThreadAffinative` interface to be propagated outside the AppDomain, but I don't know if that applies here too.

Comment: The link is obsolete, here is the version of page from 2014 http://web.archive.org/web/20140926052056/http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?572-CallContext-vs-ThreadStatic-vs-HttpContext